# verifying_blurb text displayed during Azure B2C Social Sign up [api.selfasserted] validation stays on screen

Tags: validation, templates, customization, azure-ad-b2c, look-and-feel

This looks like a bug in Azure B2C default templates...

Maybe someone has an idea on how to hide the `verifying_blurb` text that insists on staying visible when validation fails. Maybe it's my fault somewhere. Not sure.

Is there any way of hooking up to the error event raised by Azure B2C policy and hide this text after the validation stops?

See in the following screenshot that the message `Please wait while we process your information.` stays fixed below the form.

[image]

I'm using a custom .html page for `api.selfasserted`.

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
    <LoadUri>https://website.blob.core.windows.net/policies-ux/signupSocial.html</LoadUri>
</ContentDefinition>
```

**####### Edit 1 #######**

This is the `DataUri` version I'm using (1.1.0) which seems to be the latest version as of now according to this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout):

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
    <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>

 <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>
```

Tomorrow I'll try some Javascript...

Comment: Issue might be from your side. When we check with our custom template it is working fine. Are you seeing issue in B2C default templates?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this.  I was able to fix this by adding the following CSS to a custom css I loaded on the screen:

```
.verifying-modal
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be doable with CSS

```css
  #simplemodal-overlay, .simplemodal-container{
    display: none !important;
  }
```

We can also use javascript/jQuery

```js
    /* HIDE B2C MODAL OVERLAY */
    $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const $ele = $(e.target);
        $("#simplemodal-overlay, .simplemodal-container").remove();
    });
```